# Trying to learn how to use getItemViewType() with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

So before anyone chastises me about asking a question that is already asked, I have looked up a solution on this site about how to use the method getItemViewType() to present different listItems in the RecyclerView. I'm trying to learn how this works as I've even seen variations of the RecyclerView implementation itself but here is my problem. In my onBindViewHolder method, it doesn't recognize the bind() method from each of the prospective ViewHolders I've created. Can someone please tell me why?

```
public class CrimeListFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final int ITEM_TYPE_NORMAL = 0;
    private static final int ITEM_TYPE_COPS = 1;

    private RecyclerView mCrimeRecyclerView;
    private CrimeAdapter mAdapter;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime_list, container, false);

        mCrimeRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.crime_recycler_view);
        mCrimeRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        updateUI();

        return view;
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        CrimeLab crimeLab = CrimeLab.get(getActivity());
        List<Crime> crimes = crimeLab.getCrimes();

        mAdapter = new CrimeAdapter(crimes);
        mCrimeRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }



    private class CrimeHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements View.OnClickListener {

        private Crime mCrime;

        private TextView mTitleTextView;
        private TextView mDateTextView;

        public CrimeHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
            super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_crime, parent, false));
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

            mTitleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.crime_title);
            mDateTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.crime_date);
        }

        public void bind(Crime crime) {
            mCrime = crime;
            mTitleTextView.setText(mCrime.getTitle());
            mDateTextView.setText(mCrime.getDate().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    mCrime.getTitle() + " clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }

    private class PoliceHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements View.OnClickListener{

        private Crime mCrime;

        private TextView mTitleTextView;
        private TextView mDateTextView;
        private Button mPoliceButton;

        public PoliceHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent){
            super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_crime_police, parent, false));
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

            mTitleTextView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.crime_title);
            mDateTextView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.crime_date);
            mPoliceButton = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.police_button);
            mPoliceButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "call the police!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }

        public void bind(Crime crime){
            mCrime = crime;
            mTitleTextView.setText(mCrime.getTitle());
            mDateTextView.setText(mCrime.getDate().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), mCrime.getTitle() + "Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }


    private class CrimeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

        private List<Crime> mCrimes;

        public CrimeAdapter(List<Crime> crimes) {
            mCrimes = crimes;
        }

        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());

            if(viewType == ITEM_TYPE_COPS){
                return new PoliceHolder(layoutInflater, parent);
            }
            if (viewType == ITEM_TYPE_NORMAL) {
                return new CrimeHolder(layoutInflater, parent);
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Crime crime = mCrimes.get(position);
            final int itemType = getItemViewType(position);

            if(itemType == ITEM_TYPE_COPS){
                (PoliceHolder)holder.bind(crime);
            }
            if(itemType == ITEM_TYPE_NORMAL){
                (CrimeHolder)holder.bind(crime);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mCrimes.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position){
            if (mCrimes.get(position).isRequiresPolice()){
                return ITEM_TYPE_COPS;
            } else {
                return ITEM_TYPE_NORMAL;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you mean by "In my onBindViewHolder method, it doesn't recognize the bind() method from each of the prospective ViewHolders I've created"?  Do you receive a compile or runtime error/exception, or does it not behave correctly?  If it does not behave correctly, what is it doing and what is the expected behavior?

Comment: it won't compile. when I hover over bind it says  "cannot resolve method 'bind(Crime)'        It can't reach the bind method of either viewholder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not properly casting the ViewHolder to the classes you've created. Your method should look like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Crime crime = mCrimes.get(position);
    final int itemType = getItemViewType(position);

    if(itemType == ITEM_TYPE_COPS){
        ((PoliceHolder)holder).bind(crime);
    }
    if(itemType == ITEM_TYPE_NORMAL){
        ((CrimeHolder)holder).bind(crime);
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, it's always something stupid like that. thank you. I will give you credit because you answered first

Comment: Thanks, glad to be of help :D

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an extra set of parenthesis when you call the bind() method in onBindViewHolder(), to be sure that the compiler understands that you are casting the holder object and not the result of the bind() method:

```
if(itemType == ITEM_TYPE_COPS){
    ((PoliceHolder)holder).bind(crime);
}
if(itemType == ITEM_TYPE_NORMAL){
    ((CrimeHolder)holder).bind(crime);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I just got that from Tharkius. Wish I could give you both credit. 1 Upvote though;

Answer (score 0):

You are making a cast to PoliceHolder of holder.bind(crime), but you don't wan't that. You want to cast the holder to PoliceHolder and then access the method bind. For that you should do this:

```
((PoliceHolder)holder).bind(crime);
```

Hope it works.