# different patterns in one ListView

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

**Want to do**

Is it able to display 2 kinds of lists in a ListView?

Now, I display 1 pattern of log(lists) but I have to display one more new pattern on same page.
Therefore I need to display 2 patterns of lists on same page.I was using ListView and BaseAdapter but I have no idea to show 2 pattarns.

If a data includes C, shows pattern1 and if includes G, shows pattern2.

【image】

ーーーーーー

A、B、C

D、E、F

ーーーーーー

A、B、G

D、H、I、J

ーーーーーー

A、B、C

D、E、F

ーーーーーー

A、B、C

D、E、F

ーーーーーー

A、B、G

D、H、I、J

ーーーーーー

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector

Comment: I am using Xamarin.Android and XML. Do you know how to write in XML?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layouts-for-each-row

Comment: I am not sure what you mean but happy to help I guess

Comment: I am just trying to make it and I guess I can make it soon. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use [RecyclerView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/recycler-view/) to achieve this.

When `RecyclerView` has multiple `ViewHolders`, we usually override `GetItemViewType` method.

```
getItemViewType(int position)
```

This method's default implementation will always return 0, indicating that there is only 1 type of view. In your case, it is not so, and so you will need find a way to assert which row corresponds to which view type.

Besides,when we should notice the viewType parameter of following method:

```
public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
```

According to the view type, we'll need to inflate the correct layout resource and create our view holder accordingly. The RecyclerView will handle recycling different view types in a way which avoids clashing of different view types.

For example: (assume you can match your viewholders with your object's field `Type`)

```
private  const int LAYOUT_ONE = 0;
private  const int LAYOUT_TWO = 1;
```

method `GetItemViewType`:

```
public override int GetItemViewType(int position)
{
    if (items[position].Type == 0)
        return LAYOUT_ONE;
    else
        return LAYOUT_TWO;
}
```

method `OnCreateViewHolder`

```
public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view = null;
        switch (viewType)
        {
            case LAYOUT_ONE:
                view = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.customview_user_writepostbar, parent, false);
                return new CreatePostViewHolder(view);

            case LAYOUT_TWO:
                view = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.customview_postregular, parent, false);
                return new PostRegularViewHolder(view);

        }
    }
```

method `OnBindViewHolder`

```
public override void 
        OnBindViewHolder (RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        int type = GetItemViewType(position);

        switch (type)
        {
            case LAYOUT_ONE:
                CreatePostViewHolder vh2 = holder as CreatePostViewHolder;
                vh2.userFirstName.Text = UserFirstName + ", share something inspiring!";
                break;
            case LAYOUT_TWO:
                PostRegularViewHolder vh = holder as PostRegularViewHolder;
                // other code
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for polite answer! I have a question about inside of GetItemViewType(int position) . **items[position].Type** makes error because of **.Type**. You mean **position == 0** ?

Comment: The `Type` is a field of an item. I divide the different layout types according to this field. You can also divide different layout types based on a field of your item model.

Comment: You can refer to this thread for how to use `RecyclerView`:   [Trying to learn how to use getItemViewType() with RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46698897/trying-to-learn-how-to-use-getitemviewtype-with-recyclerview) .

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Finally I understand the meaning of Type and I did it.